# Problemas al insertar datos procedentes de un array en una BBDD MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Veamos. Tengo dos tablas: pedidos y pedidos_remoto. Me fijo en el campo agregado (con valor=0) de la tabla pedidos_remoto, que significa que los datos no han sido agregados a la tabla pedidos. Entonces, hago el siguiente código, para sacar aquellos registros con el valor agregado a 0:

```
function selectAgregado0MSAccess($conMSAccess){ //TESTEO APROBADO

    echo "<h3>Sácame todos los campos de la tabla de MSAccess dónde agregado=0</h3>";

    $queryMS="SELECT * FROM pedidos_remoto WHERE agregado=0";
    $lecturaMS=mysqli_query($conMSAccess, $queryMS);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($lecturaMS)){
        $datosagregado0MS[]=$row;
    }
    
    return $datosagregado0MS;
}
```

Esto me devuelve un array ($datosagregados0MS) con la siguiente forma:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(50) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "FNC"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "ZZZZYYYYP"
    [2]=>
    string(19) "2020-10-15 00:00:00"
    [3]=>
    string(13) "IKER CASILLAS"
    [4]=>
    string(11) "CAMPEONES 1"
    [5]=>
    string(9) "47391365A"
    [6]=>
    string(5) "37003"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "MOSTOLES"
    [8]=>
    string(6) "MADRID"
    [9]=>
    string(9) "784138455"
    [10]=>
    string(7) "4324324"
    [11]=>
    string(17) "GUANTES DE FUTBOL"
    [12]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [13]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [14]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [15]=>
    string(2) "20"
    [16]=>
    string(2) "30"
    [17]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [18]=>
    string(6) "334234"
    [19]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [20]=>
    string(19) "2020-10-20 00:00:00"
    [21]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [22]=>
    string(3) "3E2"
    [23]=>
    string(4) "SEUR"
    [24]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [25]=>
    string(6) "SDFAS2"
    [26]=>
    string(19) "2020-10-20 00:00:00"
    [27]=>
    string(16) "FDSFSEREWER23342"
    [28]=>
    string(9) "432432DSF"
    [29]=>
    string(9) "FDSFSFS23"
    [30]=>
    string(8) "DFSFSF3E"
    [31]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [32]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [33]=>
    NULL
    [34]=>
    string(19) "2020-10-20 00:00:00"
    [35]=>
    NULL
    [36]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [37]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [38]=>
    string(10) "EN PROCESO"
    [39]=>
    string(20) "PROVEEDOR GUANTES SL"
    [40]=>
    string(19) "2020-10-15 00:00:00"
    [41]=>
    string(19) "2020-10-26 00:00:00"
    [42]=>
    string(8) "SDSADF32"
    [43]=>
    string(19) "2020-10-27 00:00:00"
    [44]=>
    NULL
    [45]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [46]=>
    string(8) "343DSA-Z"
    [47]=>
    string(6) "MADRID"
    [48]=>
    string(9) "34243SD-P"
    [49]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
```

Toda esta explicación para que comprendáis bien la estructura de datos y de dónde vienen los datos. El problema es que ejecuto este código para intentar meter los datos del array en MySQL en la tabla pedidos:

```
function insertarAgregado0MSAccessIntoMySQL($datosagregado0MS){
    
    foreach ($datosagregado0MS as $row) {

        // var_dump($row); die();
        $sql="INSERT INTO pedidos VALUES ('".implode("','",$row)."');";
        if(mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql)){
            echo "Se han insertado los datos correctamente en pedidos";
        } else {
            echo "Error:".$sql."<br>"."No se han insertado los datos de forma correcta";
        }
    }
}
```

y no funciona. Me muestra por pantalla todos los datos del array pero no me inserta y me muestra el mensaje de error. No sé a qué se debe el fallo. En SQL la sentencia ejecuta de forma correcta, así que supongo que el fallo viene de PHP. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

He comprendido que el fallo se debe a que $datosagregado0MS tiene un dato más (porque pedidos_remoto tiene un campo más) que la BBDD de destino, y probablemente el problema venga por ahí. De modo que voy a abrir una nueva pregunta relacionada con la mejor lógica para abordar esta problemática.